# Architecture to process AWS S3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-athena

I am working on a POC where we have millions of existing S3 compressed json files (uncompressed 3+ MB, with nested objects and arrays) and more being added every few minutes.  We need to perform computations on top of the uncompressed data (per file basis) and store it to a DB table where we can then perform some column operations. The most common solution I found online is

```
S3 (Add/update event notification) => SQS (main queue => dlq queue) <=> AWS lambda
```

We have a DB table for all S3 bucket key names that are being successfully loaded, so I can query this table and use the AWS SDK Node.js package to send messages to the SQS main queue. For newly added/updated files, S3 event notification will take care of it.

I think the above architecture will work in my case, but are there any other AWS services I should look at?

I looked at AWS Athena which can read my compressed files and can give me the raw output but since I have big nested objects and arrays on top of which I need to perform computation, I am not sure if it's ideal to write such complex logic in SQL.

I would really appreciate some guidance here.

Comment: Without knowing much about the structure of the input or output data, this seems like a reasonable approach if you need the data in a database in near realtime.  SQS has a Lambda trigger which allows batching of requests to the Lambda (up to 10) so that helps reduce the Lambda concurrency limit you may reach if you try to process all legacy data up front.  The other option may be using AWS Glue, however, this is more appropriate if you're batch processing data (say) once a day, rather than continuously processing it as it arrives.  Depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks @Norman. The payload structure is like
`{
  "id": 1,
  "caseNumber": 1234567890,
  "accountNumber": 0987654321,
  "equipmentsUsage": "<Array of objects>",
  "logs": "<Array of objects>"
}`
We will be performing computations on all the objects inside **equipmentsUsage** (upto 50 objects) and also on all the objects inside **logs** (upto 5000). Output will be an object with few key value pairs which we will add to the DB.

Comment: Does the data need to appear in the destination in (near) realtime?

Comment: @Norman No, we are not looking for (near) realtime data to the user right away but would prefer to have the data ready in case user comes back after a few minutes. Also, we might send the user a notification that their data metrics are ready to be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to query the data in the future in ways you can't anticipate, I would strongly suggest you explore the Athena solution, since you would be plugging a very powerful SQL engine on top of your data. Athena can query directly compressed json and export to other data formats that are a lot more efficient to query (like parquet or orc) and support complex data structures.

The flow would be:

`S3 (new file) => Athena ETL (json to, say, parquet)`

see e.g. [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-etl-data-pipelines-using-amazon-athenas-federated-queries-and-user-defined-functions/).

For already existing data you can do a one-off query to convert it to the appropriate format (partitioning would be useful if your data volume is big as it seems it is). Having good partitioning is key to obtain good performance on Athena and you will need to think carefully about it on your ETL. More on partitioning, e.g., [there](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html).